# Compare two lists, item by item, using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to compare two lists, item by item. How can I express the following code using linq?

```
bool result = true;
var list1 = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
for (int index = 0; index < list1.Count(); index++)
{
   result &= list1[index] == list2[index];
}
```

Comment: Does the order matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Determines whether two sequences are equal by comparing the elements by using the default equality comparer for their type.

**Example:**

```
bool result = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

Comment: Linq is so powerful. Sometime it will conquer the world. Btw I would consider to check count of items in lists before enumerating them. Something like `result = (list1.Count == list2.Count) && list1.SequenceEqual(list2)`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Why doesn't the Linq implementation doesn't do this itself?

Comment: @RGraham nope, it does not - it simply gets enumerators from both enumerables and iterates while both have items and those items are equal. There is nothing specific to argument type (array, ICollection etc). [Proof](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)