# Comparing two lists with LINQ, and retrieve the different items

Tags: c#, linq, list

Assume I have the following object `foo` and its properties listed below:

```
class foo
public string name
public string property1
public string property2
```

Now let's instantiate two lists of `foo`: `List<foo>()`

The **first list** contains two `foo` objects:

```
new foo() = 
{
   name = "name",
   property1 = "random value",
   property1 = "random value"
}

new foo() = 
{
   name = "name",
   property1 = "random value",
   property1 = "random value"
}
```

The **second list** contains one `foo` object:

```
new foo() = 
{
   name = "name",
   property1 = "random value",
   property1 = "random value"
}
```

Is it possible using **LINQ** to compare and return a new `List<foo>` that contains the differences between these two lists (or any other list for that matter)? **Taking into consideration that item order and *any* property value that does not match are also considered as a difference.**

This was helpful for primitive objects:
[Compare two lists, item by item, using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809841/compare-two-lists-item-by-item-using-linq) but does not provide a way to return a new list with the differences.

### EDIT

@CSharpie reopened... Also now the question looks very poorly defined - i.e. what is expected result for {1,2,3,4} and {1,3,4}? Possibly OP is looking for some sort of diff..

@AlexeiLevenkov The output should be 2. Or for a list of {1,2,3,4} and {1,3,2, 4} the output should be {3,2} since the order (or values) of 3 and 2 have changed from the original list.

Comment: See Linq Set Operations https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Set-Operators-374f34fe

Comment: @CSharpie reopened... Also now the question looks very poorly defined - i.e. what is expected result for {1,2,3,4} and {1,3,4}? Possibly OP is looking for some sort of diff..

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, you are right. 
OP: You need to clarify what you consider as a difference between two lists and also what role the order of the items in those lists play. Best is to specify a frew examples with desired outcomes.

Comment: Sorry guys my bad, will update the question in a bit.

Comment: @CSharpie please see my edit. If it's not clear please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LINQ to Objects to find items in one collection that do not match another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647698/using-linq-to-objects-to-find-items-in-one-collection-that-do-not-match-another)

Comment: @RichardHein The objects are of the same type in this case. (Does this solution take into consideration the order of items as differences?)

Comment: Does the order of the returned results matter? You say 1,2,3,4 diff 1,3,2,4 is 3,2, but I don't see any obvious way to determine the ordering.

Comment: It doesn't matter, but comparing 1,3,2,4 to the initial list 1,2,3,4 returns that 3 and 2 have been "displaced"... Might also return 1 in that case if the value of 1 changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) LINQ method:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 5 };
List<int> b = new List<int>{ 2, 3};
var result = a.Except(b).Union(b.Except(a)).ToList();
```

In set theory, `(A-B)+(B-A)` is equivalent to the differences between the two of them.

Comment: Does this work for complex objects? Such as `foo` as described above?

Comment: of course, you just need to write your own Comparor. It's a hint, you need to try it from here

Comment: another hint is, look into MoreLinq or ExtraLinq, they might have a new extension that meets your need. But even they do, you still need to write a comparor to determine why 2 objects are equal

Comment: How will this method differentiate the order?